# how to set a seekbars progress with a decimal value that is a float, accuratly?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, seekbar, android-seek

hey guys i am trying to make a set temperature app which has a seek bar and a textview. the readings of my temperature include values like 33.3 and 34.5. I know the code fore setting a seekbars progress is

```
seekbarTemperature.setProgress(int);
```

but i want to use float values like 33.3 or 39.8. if i convert a float into an int it rounds the value up to a whole number like 33 or 34. this will not position my seekbar properly because my seekbar will be positioned at 33 when my textview says 33.3. As i have also set the seekbar to increment or decrement by 0.1 it is vital that my seekbar is positioned accurately to the decimal. So can someone tell me how to set the seekbars progress position exactly to i.e. 33.4 not 33 or 34?

Answer (score 9):

you can not show ProgressBar progress with double value.
but you can go for a simple mathematics.

set the ProgressBar maximum progress to 1000.
now when you want to show progress with value 33.3, update the ProgressBar with 333 like

```
 progressBar.setProgress(333);
```

Comment: this solution helped me immensely (in 2021). thank you!

Comment: Works for javascript and HTML5 seekbar as well.

Answer (score 2):

instead to have the seekbar going from `0` to `100` you could have it going from `0` to `1000` and `33.4` should be `334`.